# What is the relation between the different codimensions (e.g. left-right, contact) of map germs?

Tags: singularity-theory

I would like to clarify the relations between the different codimension conceptions of map germs. I studied mostly from the new book of [Mond and Nuno-Ballesteros](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-34440-5), another source is [Wall](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/13/6/481/296417?redirectedFrom=PDF). Most of my questions are yes-no questions, I would like to find explicit reference for them.

Let $f: (\mathbb{R}^n, 0) \to (\mathbb{R}^p, 0) $ be a smooth (or analytic) germ. Let $\mathcal{G}$ any of the groups $\mathcal{R}$ (right), $\mathcal{L}$ (left), $\mathcal{A}$ (leftright), $\mathcal{K}$ (contact) or $\mathcal{C}$ (''left part'' of $\mathcal{K}$). Each of them induces a $\mathcal{G}$-codimension and a $\mathcal{G}_e$-codimension of $f$.
Let $Q(f)$ be the local algebra of $f$. Questions:

1. Are the following true in general?
   $\mathcal{A}-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{R}-\mbox{codim}(f)$; $\mathcal{A}-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{L}-\mbox{codim}(f)$; $\mathcal{A}_e-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{R}_e-\mbox{codim}(f)$;
   $\mathcal{A}_e-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{L}_e-\mbox{codim}(f)$.
2. Does $\mathcal{K}-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{A}-\mbox{codim}(f)$ hold in general?
3. When is $\mathcal{G}_e-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{G}-\mbox{codim}(f)$ true? I guess, it holds for $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{R}$, $\mathcal{L}$, $\mathcal{A}$ in general, but does not hold for $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{K}$.
   (For $\mathcal{A}$ I found [here](http://www.worksing.icmc.usp.br/main_site/2016/minicourse3_notes.pdf) the ''Wilson formula'' Prop. 3.1.7.)
4. Which property of $f$ is related with the three cases ($\mathcal{K}-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq / \geq / = \mathcal{K}_e-\mbox{codim}(f)$)?
5. $\mathcal{K}_e-\mbox{codim}(f) \leq \mathcal{A}_e-\mbox{codim}(f)$ is not true in general (a counterexample is $f(x, y) = (x, y^3+xy)$). Which property of $f$ is related with the three cases?
6. Is it true that $\mathcal{C}_e-\mbox{codim}(f)= p \cdot \dim Q(f)$, and $\mathcal{C}-\mbox{codim}(f)= (p-1) \cdot \dim Q(f)$?
7. What is the relation between $\mathcal{K}-\mbox{codim}(f)$, $\mathcal{K}_e-\mbox{codim}(f)$ and $\dim Q(f)$?